# GCM is not working on Kindle fire devices: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, kindle-fire

Its throwing exception  while calling `GCM.register(this,SENDER_ID);`

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf`

What is alternative option of GCM on Amazon devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindle Fire don't have "Google Play Services" library installed, so GCM won't work. Try [ADM](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm.html) instead.

Comment: I have the Google Play services but i think i get the error because this app always crashes on my Samsung GT-N5100. Its running CyanogenMod 12.1

Answer (score 1):

GCM have some limitation,

In android device must have google play store,
second one is android device configure with google account (This limitation in some devices.).

You got error this because kindle dose not have this package which gcm needed.