# Uncaught exception while generating regid in GCM

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#run)

Below is the code:

```
    if (checkPlayService()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);
        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }
    private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msg = "";
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working in Background");
                Log.i(TAG, "RegId = "+regid);
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                Log.i(TAG, "RegId = "+regid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 msg = "Error :" + e.getMessage();
                 Log.i(TAG, msg);
            }
            msg = "Device Register with " + regid;
            Log.i(TAG, msg);
            sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
            // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
            // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
            // message using the 'from' address in the message.

            // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
            storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            registrationid = msg + "\n";
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration ID"+registrationid);
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}


protected void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, regid);
}

protected void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regid);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside getRegistrationId function");
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString("PROPERTY_REG_ID", "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,
            Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

private int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getSharedPreferences(UserRegister.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public boolean checkPlayService() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "Check Play Services" + resultCode);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I am running the code I am getting the below Log cat values :

```
07-22 09:58:15.069: D/dalvikvm(32393): GC_CONCURRENT freed 127K, 3% free 6716K/6919K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-22 09:58:15.098: I/UserRegistration(32393): Check Play Services0

07-22 09:58:15.098: I/UserRegistration(32393): Inside getRegistrationId function

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): Registration not found.

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): Working in Background

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): RegId = 

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): Check Play Services0

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): Inside getRegistrationId function

07-22 09:58:15.108: I/UserRegistration(32393): Registration not found.

07-22 09:58:15.118: I/UserRegistration(32393): Working in Background

07-22 09:58:15.118: I/UserRegistration(32393): RegId =
```

The problem I am facing in the `AsychTask` when I put `log.i` above the `regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);` I am getting above log message if  I am using the below code snippet:

```
        Log.i(TAG, "Working in Background");
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    Log.i(TAG, "RegId = "+regid);
```

Log cat:

```
07-22 10:10:55.748: W/dalvikvm(432): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)

07-22 10:10:55.748: W/dalvikvm(432): 
threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
```

Please help me I am not able to find out why this is happening? I am not able to generate the `regid` also.

I have modified the Catch a bit instead of IOException I have change it to Exception then I am getting the below logs

```
07-22 11:16:35.868: I/UserRegistration(2040): Check Play Services0

07-22 11:16:35.868: I/UserRegistration(2040): Inside getRegistrationId function

07-22 11:16:35.868: I/UserRegistration(2040): Registration not found.

07-22 11:16:35.868: I/UserRegistration(2040): Working in Background

07-22 11:16:35.878: I/UserRegistration(2040): Check Play Services0

07-22 11:16:35.878: I/UserRegistration(2040): Inside getRegistrationId function

07-22 11:16:35.878: I/UserRegistration(2040): Registration not found.

07-22 11:16:35.878: I/UserRegistration(2040): Error :null

07-22 11:16:35.878: I/UserRegistration(2040): Device Register with 

07-22 11:16:35.928: I/UserRegistration(2040): Working in Background

07-22 11:16:35.948: I/UserRegistration(2040): Error :null

07-22 11:16:35.948: I/UserRegistration(2040): Device Register with
```

now it is going to other line but I am not able to get the RegId it is showing as null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.splitwise"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.registration.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.registration.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.registration.UserRegister"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity 
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"></meta-data>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.registration.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.registration" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.example.registration.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is throwing exception:

```
 int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

Whenever you will try to run your application devices which don't support **Google play services** then it will throw `Exception`,

Devices which are not supporting Google play services:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-IN
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

so you should use try catch for that method.

Final conclusion is that your device does not support `Google Play Services` or have disabled (need to install) it.

Look at this(Same problem on Kindle devices):
[GCM is not working on Kindle fire devices: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833590/gcm-is-not-working-on-kindle-fire-devices-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexcepti)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have logged a result code after this line  Log.i(TAG, "Check Play Services" + resultCode); if you see the log cat message it is displaying Check Play Services0 this means the resultcode is 0 which is Success. If the device is not supported it would have logged the message as "This device is not supported" as I have logged it just before the finish().

Comment: Then this will resolve your problem ? If exception will occur then return from catch block.

Comment: if the exception would have occured in the Async task then it would have displayed some message, but it is saying uncaught exception.

Comment: and also the device is mention in the link Sony Ericsson Wt19i

Comment: But your application getting crashed at that point, i think you need to update Google play services from playstore then it will work,

Comment: post your menifest file.

Comment: Added the Manifest file